# Average ratio between two columns

Tags: sql

I've been collecting tweets, and running some queries on them.
In one of the queries I'm trying to find all users that have an an average follower to friend ratio of at least two (i.e. twice as many followers as friends). Finding the average is important because I have collected the tweets of some users multiple times, at different times. Their friends or followers can change, so they can come up with multiple ratios.

I can do it without averages, resulting in multiple results for some users

```
SELECT screenname,followers,friends,usertweets, followers/friends AS FFRatio 
FROM tweets
WHERE friends >0 AND followers/friends>2
```

When I try to use AVG, I get errors, and no results.

```
SELECT screenname,followers,friends,usertweets, AVG(followers/friends) AS FFRatio 
FROM tweets
WHERE friends >0 AND AVG(followers/friends)>2
```

Can you tell me what is wrong, please?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add back the appropriate tag for the database you are using.

Comment: @philipxy I assumed dividing by 0 would cause problems

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain the problem.

Comment: @philipxy your corrected answer? I can only see one other answer to this question

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want. Please give example input and desired output. Do you want an output row for every input row, with the average ratio over all rows for that screenname added? Do you also want the average number of the input tweets value, ie input tweets is the number of tweets since last observation/row? Or is tweets cumulative? Or is tweets just the number of input rows, because you add rows on tweeting? Similarly, are followers & friends new ones, or cumulative? If you don't tell us about your input & desired output then we can't know.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
SELECT screenname, AVG(followers/friends) AS FFRatio 
FROM tweets
WHERE friends > 0
GROUP BY screenname
HAVING AVG(followers/friends) > 2;
```

I assume `screenname` is what you mean by "user".  Don't put extraneous columns in the `SELECT` -- the columns should either be in the `GROUP BY` or arguments to aggregation functions.

Comment: Yes screenname is user. But I also want the other columns in SELECT to be displayed. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: If you have only one row per each `screenname` you could put them inside the same block and add them in `group by`. Or you could use this as a subquery and join it back to `tweets` table for extra data

Comment: @ConsiderMe   some screennames have multiple rows, as some some of them tweeted more than once. Would I have to use a subquery? Because I want to display everything that in the SELECT of my question.

Comment: You could abuse a bit and use `MAX()` for every column that you want to include to get the values you need only once, but that depends on your data. Sample data for one user that has > 1 row would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your test for > 0 is not necessarily executed before the division. If you have these in the same condition then you can use a CASE, which executes cases in order. You could move the ratio to a HAVING, which is evaluated after WHERE.

To average over the ratios per screen name, GROUP BY screenname.

```
SELECT screenname, AVG(followers/friends) AS FFRatio 
FROM tweets
WHERE friends > 0
GROUP BY screenname
HAVING FFRatio > 2
```

(AVG is an aggregate function and must appear in HAVING or SELECT. Other columns in the GROUP BY can appear in the SELECT. If a column is not single-valued per group then there is no one value to SELECT. But if columns are single-valued per group and you want them output then you can add them to the GROUP BY & SELECT.)

**BUT** Probably what you really want is people who have no friends but have followers or have friends and also a good enough ratio. For a single ratio per screenname you could display a blank when there is no ratio and a number when there is. But how to average ratios in these cases?--there is not always a ratio.

**BUT** It is extremely unlikely that the average of a ratio or average is relevant. Eg averaging 100/4 and 99/99 gives (25+1)/2 = 13. But the average over all observations is 199/103. Similarly in your case you may have observations with followers but no friends hence with no ratio but that should be taken into account.

If you want some notion of "recent" ratio then you could use AVG(followers)/AVG(friends) where the values are from some standard time interval. Maybe your input is the activity for such an interval or the approximation of one. (You'd still be presuming a uniform distribution of observations over time.) If so:

```
SELECT screenname, AVG(followers) AS FoAvg, AVG(friends) AS FrAvg, 
    CASE WHEN FrAvg = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE FoAvg/FrAvg END AS FFRatio
FROM tweets
GROUP BY screenname
HAVING CASE WHEN FrAvg = 0 AND FoAvg > 0 THEN 1
   WHEN FrAvg > 0 AND FoAvg/FrAvg > 2 THEN 1
   ELSE 0 END
```

You have to decide just what you want your query to return. But it's *extremely unlikely* to be an average of ratios.